# MATLAB pointers that access memory

Tags: matlab, pointers

Is it possible to make pointers in MATLAB that accesses the actual memory locations? I would like to use pointers to reference certain structures that I've made, but I want to be able to modify the structures through the pointer. I would use C++ but I can't use C++ on the servers I'm working with.

This is the best thing I've found so far, but it doesn't look like what I want.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-pointers.html

If it's not possible I have other ways around it, but it makes my code significantly less extensible.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be working with pointers in Matlab? What are you trying to achieve, I can't imagine when you would need to use a pointer in Matlab, without there at least being another way to approach the problem.

Comment: I have a bunch of nodes that need to be connected in a fairly large network. If I were working in C++, the best course of action is definitely pointers/references. I'm essentially setting up a tree-like system with a lot of relations between nodes.

Comment: Using oop and handles might be an option: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html but be aware, oop in matlab is slow. Probably implementing your network using a (sparse) adjacent matrix is the fastest possibility.